# querying and joining multiple tables. Only selecting a single records out of many that may exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, inner-join

I'm having some difficulties with this query, I'm basically not sure if something like this is possible in one shot.

tbl1

```
 RefNum         ClientID       SWID
 1              17             79
 3              17             90
 18             23             88
 34             18             88
 56             34             90
```

tbl2

```
 SWID            SCity
 79              Syracuse
 90              Elmond
 88              Albureque
```

In tbl1 I can have multiple ClientID records that will have a distinctive RefNum - since that is the primary key; Auto Increment.

I'm only looking to be able to select TOP 1 for each clientID (only one record per Client). Also, I'm hoping to Join tbl2 using SWID in order to get the *SCity*.

What I hope it looks like in the end is this (wishful thinking) I dont even know if this is possible with one query

```
Count      City
1          Syracuse
2          Elmond
1          Albureque
```

The reason why I only have Count = 1 for Albureque is because, for Albureque (SWID = 88), the same client appears 2 (clientID = 17). In this case I'd only count it once.

I have about 480000 records, and I basically need a summary report that will display the count of unduplicated ClientID's by SCity. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
 RefNum         ClientID       SWID
 1              17             79
 2              17             79
 18             23             79
 3              17             90
 87             17             88
```

Desired end result

```
 Count              City
 2                  Syracuse (79)
 1                  Elmond  (90)
 1                  Albureque (88)
```

So basically Client 17 has two instances of same SWID (79) so we only count it as one. But Client 17 also has another record for another SWID 90 and 88, in this case, we still want to count the records as 1 for 90 and 88.

Syracuse has 2 because Client 17 has Syracuse (79) and Client 23 has Syracuse as well - since client 17 has 2 records, we rolled them up into 1 + 1 (Client 23) = 2.

The even tricker part is that SWID might be different sometimes, but the actual City is the SAME. So as example ClientID = 9 can have SWID = 109 and SWID = 198, but in tbl2 - the SCITY is SAN FRANCISCO in both cases. The reason for that is tbl2 is not a reference table really, SWID is actually associated with a Community person, who might be located in the same city but simply different office. So SWID = 109 is John Doe at San Francisco, and SWID =198 is Jane Smith at San Francisco also.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Would TOP 1 mean the row with the minimum of RefNum for each clientID? Or is it OK to return any row with a clientID, as long as it is only one row for each clietn ID?

Comment: @Yunnosch We want to make sure that we show client for each city individually. So if it has 1 records for City = 88 then show as 1. Then if it has 2 records for city = 90 then STILL show it as 1. Basically if client has 1 records for 5 different cities, we want to show the client as 1 for each of the five cities

Comment: ClientID 17 is in Syracuse (79) and Elmond (90), not in Albureque (88) as per your sample data above.

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar - plese see edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `join` and `count(distinct)`:

```
select t2.scity, count(distinct t1.clientId)
from tbl1 t1 join
     tbl2 t2
     on t1.swid = t2.swid
group by t2.scity;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this query works. If a ClientID has 2 records for the same office, I'd like to count it as 1. however, if same ClientID has a record for City A, and one record for City B then I'd like to have it count as 1 for City A and 1 for City B - will this work that way?

Comment: Use this query.

Comment: Yes. count(distinct t1.clientId), meaning only one per clientid will be counted each city.

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar - even if the SWID is different but SCITY in tbl2 is the same?

Comment: Did you mean you may have SWID 79 as Syracuse and SWID 80 as Syracuse as well?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar - Yes